# Not Recursively enumerable sets

Tags: logic

Can someone tell me how to show that $A = \{ x : {\phi}_{x}^{1}(x) \uparrow \}$ is a not recursively enumerable set?

I am really struggling.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, what is $\phi_x^1$? Specifically, what is the superscript $1$?

Comment: Ignore 1. I think it's wrong.

Comment: I hope you've seen http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/loopsnoop.html ?

Comment: I have not, but i do not seem to understand how that helps me.

Comment: It's a proof, in poem form, that the halting set is not recursive. (This result is equivalent, assuming $\phi_x$ represents the $x$th Turing machine.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens I believe that $\phi^n_e(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ represents the $e$-th $n$-ary computable function in this case?

Comment: @Patrick Stevens: that is standard notation. The $1$ means that the function takes one argument, and the $x$ is the index.  It was common in many texts to track the number of arguments explicitly, so $\phi^1_x$ and $\phi^2_x$ are different functions

Comment: @Angela: the level of detail in the question makes it seem as if the question is just a homework problem. You can improve the question by including more context: where did you encounter the problem? What topics have you seen in that course recently? What have you already tried? These will help others write more useful answers, and make the question more useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

The Halting Problem is represented by the set $\overline{A} = \{ x : {\phi}_{x}(x) \downarrow \}$. This set is known to be r.e. but not recursive. If its complement $A$ were r.e., then the Halting Problem would be recursive (a set is recursive *iff* both it and its complement are r.e.)

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.